# photoswipe plugin shows me UNDEFINED on closing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using `Jquery Mobile 1.0` and `PhotoSwipe plugin` for gallary. My problem is when i open gallary photos it works well but `when i close` the photoswipe it shows me a **blank screen with UNDEFINED on the top left corer of the screen**, Can anybody tell me how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am answering to my own question and i hope this will help to others :

I am missing `rel="external"` in anchor tag, this is important, if you don't this will mess with how jQuery Mobile works.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be this [issue/pull request](https://github.com/codecomputerlove/PhotoSwipe/pull/311) of crashes on iOS